# How can I use Drag and Drop to reorder a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I know that drag and drop can be used to transfer data throughout and between apps. I'm not interested in that. All I want is to use drag and drop functionality to reorder a table view without transferring data. How do I do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are performing a drag on a **single item locally**, you can use `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)`. In order to do this, you need to implement [UITableViewDragDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view).

### Setup

Start by setting your delegates. Setting `dragInteractionEnabled` is required for iPhones.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dragDelegate = self
    tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

### UITableViewDragDelegate

Notice that the array is returning a single item. If you return more than one item, then the `UITableViewDropDelegate` methods will be used instead of `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)`. You must set a local object.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
    dragItem.localObject = data[indexPath.row]
    return [ dragItem ]
}
```

### Moving

This is where the moving happens and is actually a part of `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Update the model
    let mover = data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    data.insert(mover, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

You can also use `tableView(_:canMoveRow:at:`) and `tableView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt: toProposedIndexPath:)` if needed.

You can read more here...

- [Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop)
- [Adopting Drag and Drop in a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view)

Comment: This is actually simplest and the best answer out there.

Comment: Fantastic answer, so easy to implement too. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks! Pointing out one thing (which you're more than welcome to clarify for me): I also use `canMoveRow:at:` and `targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:toProposedIndexPath:`, and I got weird behavior when I used your implementation of `itemsForBeginning:forSession:atIndexPath` (it would allow dragging of items that were not supposed to be moved) -- simply returning an empty array fixed it for me.

Comment: Same here. In my case, the data model includes all but the last row, so if the user tries to move the last row, there is an out of bounds situation in the data model. This happens before canMoveRow:at: is called. Checking for this condition and returning an empty array works nicely.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer for this really confusing, and found that implementing `UITableViewDragDelegate` is not what is required here. Basically:

- If you want to just be able to reorder a table view using drag and drop then **don't** implement `UITableViewDragDelegate` and instead just implement the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)` method of UITableViewDelegate as such:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Update the model
    let mover = data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    data.insert(mover, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

- Otherwise if you want to be able to drag and drop items between apps or views etc then you will need to implement the `UITableViewDragDelegate` and the methods that come with that, e.g,

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]{
    // Handle here
}
```

and

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    // Handle Drop Functionality
}
```

etc. Not going into too much detail on that, but you will find tutorials on dragging / dropping between different views and apps elsewhere. However, for a simple reordering of tableview cells using drag and drop, go with the first option and **don't** implement `UITableViewDragDelegate`.

Hope this is helpful, as I got a bit confused between the two approaches.

Comment: But if I go with the first option I can't long press to rearrange.

Comment: How are you entering the movement mode then? `UITableViewDragDelegate` is what seems to give the long-press-to-drag/drop behavior.

Comment: The reorder control (horizontal-bar "grippy" in the cell) is needed. Put your table into "edit mode" to get the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can [adopt Drag and Drop in a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view)

In order to do that, in addition to regular `delegate = self` and `dataSource = self`, you need to add

```
tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true // Enable intra-app drags
tableView.dragDelegate = self
tableView.dropDelegate = self
```

That's it. The rest of it is to figure out how to implement the delegate methods above for both visual effects and data transfer.

When data is transferred between apps, the receiving app implements the methods of `dropDelegate`, the sending app implements the methods of `dragDelegate`. Now it's the same table view, it implements both.

*You can stop reading now, instead, you can read the link at the top. Below is my understanding of the linked document. I'm half-baked in this topic, but I have made it work myself.*

**For dragDelegate**

Implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]` for providing data. In many/most cases, `[UIDragItem]` array only contains 1 element, cuz usually only one item is dragged. `UIDragItem` contains an `NSItemProvider` object which carries transferred data.

**For dropDelegate**

Implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool` to tell the table view whether this drop action should be process.

Implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal` to add a visual indication of dropping item. `.move` will add a "moving there" animation, `.copy` will add a plus sign to indicate copy action. If this func is not implemented, you get no visual cue, and I don't recommend it, but it's still optional.

Implement `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator)` for actual dropping the data. Regular moving rows is like moving a row from A to B. A is the original and B is the destination. Now in the case of drag and drop, one way you can do is that, you can get destination B from `coordinator.destinationIndexPath`. A's indexPath can be stored beforehand in the `dragDelegate` method `UIDragItem`'s `itemProvider`, and now get it back thru `coordinator.session.loadObject(ofClass:)`. Now you have A and B, you can either do `tableView.move(at:to:)` or delete one row then insert the row to the new indexPath.

Again, you can read Apple's document in the link at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need UITableViewDragDelegate for this.
First add this when ever you want to start editiyng/rearranging you table:
`table.isEditing = true`
Then add these delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    allRides.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

After Swift 4 try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.deviceOrderingTableView.delegate = self
     self.deviceOrderingTableView.dataSource = self
}

extension DevicesOrderingVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.model.count 
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       //configure Cells here
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update the model
        self.model.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
        debugPrint(self.model)
        self.deviceOrderingTableView.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Output image:

[image]