# How to move cells between table sections with realm?

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, cell

In my project I am using tableView with two sections. I need to move cells within one section or between sections using the method - moveRowAt. Then I write it in Realm.

In my code cells move between sections but in one section I can't swap them.

```
override func tableView(\_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let task = sourceIndexPath.section == 0 ? importantTask[sourceIndexPath.row] : currentTask[sourceIndexPath.row] //choose from which section the task will be taken

    let type = destinationIndexPath.section == 0 ? TaskPriority.important : TaskPriority.normal // change the type of the task (it depends in which section the task will be located)

    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
    task.type = type // change task type to new type
   }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is a bit unclear - it seems you're asking about how to code with tableViews and there are a LOT of [references](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DuiTableView+moveRowAt) here on SO and tutorials that show how to do that. It also seems unrelated to Realm (and cell). Have you reviewed those? Take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270449/how-can-i-use-drag-and-drop-to-reorder-a-uitableview) for some very specific details.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131236/4081597